# Styling a font exceeding its text bounding box

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am having issues styling a custom and fancy [`@font-face`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) on a `a` link.

The font (*[Alex Brush](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Alex+Brush)*) goes outside of its boundaries (by boundaries, I mean the clickable section in this case), which is usually not a problem for browsers. However, I have noticed that when I use a different color for the `:hover` state, the exceeding section keeps the non-hovered link color.

This appears on Chrom{ium|e} (I am using Chromium 31 on Ubuntu 13.10) but not on Firefox. After further testing, I notice that other strange glitches happen depending on how you play with your mouse and tabs, ...

TL;DR: you can [try it online](http://jsbin.com/aHEfasu/5/watch).

Or, here is some HTML you can play with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a>!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
a {
  font-family: 'Alex Brush';
  font-size: 400px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Here is the glitch I get when `:hover`ing the link:

[image: Font glitch]

Is it possible to tell the bounding box to include the entire font?

Bonus question: On top of fixing the bounding box for styling purposes, is it possible to fix it once and for all? The use case would be to have a proper clickable section that would include all the text, without using `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: In Chrome 32 on Win 7, I don’t see such a phenomenon (the glyph turns all green on mouseover), but the glyph extends outside the box (this can be seen e.g. by setting `outline: solid black 1px` on the `a` element), which might be normal (depending on font design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I looked at [a similar issue last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552361/webfont-hover-color-part-of-text-not-changing-color/20563046) last month. The exact same bug was addressed there, and I've seen it happen there too.

But in the mean time, this issue seems to be fixed. The current version of Chrome (Versie 32.0.1700.76 m) shows the glyph being properly colored on `:hover`. Both your example as the example in the link above now work fine. I'm pretty sure the issue will be/has been fixed in Chromium as well.

Check out [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552361/webfont-hover-color-part-of-text-not-changing-color/20563046#20563046) if you want to know more about what font-specifics made this bug happen.

Comment: Exactly 4y down the line, and this has been long addressed. Gotta assume it was a browser bug. FWIW, I remember trying solutions below and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Works normally in Chrome

I Don't have Chromium, but I often hear about sites that are buggy on Chromium, I don't know any 'normal' person who uses it which is why I don't test in Chromium

anyway, this is a weird possible solution, but it might work?

```
a:hover {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 green;
}
```

Comment: Can you specify which version of Chrome and OS you are using please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a menu and looked at RoeIn's initial answer, which he linked to, but this put the whole menu alignment out. However, the solution below worked for me:

```
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
```

Or whatever dimensions best suit your purpose. As long as the padding equals the negative margin it doesn't put other elements out either.

Ignoring discussions of what a 'normal' person might use for a browser, this problem exists in Safari as well.